# How to scrape data from a website with similar “#” urls in menu tabs using R?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to scrape stock data from other tabs of the following website: http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35178706978554988 But all of them have same urls. when I try to use "rvest" library function such as `read_html()` , `html_nodes()` and `html_text()` , I can just scrape data from the main tab. Switching between tabs get same results. I tried to use following code, but still couldn't get appropriate results.

Previously I could extract some info such as "InsCode" and "ZTitad" stored in the "" section using "rvest". But because all other tabs' data are not written in the "html-source" section, I didn't have any idea what to do.

```r
    #Scraping Libraries
    library(rvest)
    library(jsonlite)

    #Target website
    my_url<-"http://www.tsetmc.com/Loader.aspx?ParTree=151311&i=35178706978554988"
    pagesource <- read_html(my_url)
    content<- pagesource %>% html_node("script") %>% html_text()
    data <- fromJSON(content)
```

Ultimately I want to export "حقیقی-حقوقی" tab data into a data-frame to continue my other analysis.

Comment: http://www.tsetmc.com/tsev2/data/CodalContent.aspx?s=شپاس&r=12  but I don't know enough R to handle the conversion to a useful json object. I tried rjson::toJSON  and then jsonlite::stream_in with gsub but got a factor.